# How to access service locator object inside a controller in ZF3?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I am trying to access service locator object inside my controller but unable to do this.
I tried online help but most of them are following approach for `ZF2`

Previously Servicelocator access in `zf2` was a breeze, I just had to do $this->getServiceLocator();

I have tried creating factory Class for my controller and Created  createService method there but it says I have to implement `__invoke()` method too.

My Objective is to do something like this

```
public function getPropertyTable()
{
    if (!$this->PropertyTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->PropertyTable = $sm->get('Application\Model\PropertyTable');
    }
    return $this->PropertyTable;
}
```

Can anyone provide me a complete steps to achieve this?

I have tried to implement almost all Answers related to Servicelocator before asking this question, so please help me before marking this as Duplicate or something, ignore the typos

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GetServiceLocator in Zend Framework 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974794/getservicelocator-in-zend-framework-3)

Comment: In ZF2, it was established that use Service locator in controller was a VERY VERY VERY BAD BAD BAD practice. it's not possible/advised to use that trick again in ZF3

Comment: @Hooli thanks, I understand and agree with your view completely, I know that that's why the whole flow for service manager was changed in ZF3. but that is the reason I asked this question, I don't know how can I call functions of my model inside the controller. Please see me as a Novice who is learning this tech.  I hope if you could provide me an example how can I call a model function inside Controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks everyone to tell me I am doing it the wrong way. 
 Some more research on this topic helped me to get my issue resolved 
 here is what I have done to solve it

**Create Factory class for your Controller**
        You have to create a factory class for your controller which will implement  FactoryInterface of zend.
        in there you have to call

```
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
 {
       return new ListController($container->get(PropertyInterface::class));
 }
```

here I am passing PropertyInterface refrence which is implemented by my another table called Property Table in which I have given body to all my inteface functions for model
        like searchProperty()

**Add factory class in config file module.config.php for your controller**
        instructing config file to let our factory create the object for our controller

```
'controllers' => [
            'factories' => [
                // Update the following line:
                Controller\ListController::class => Factory\ListControllerFactory::class,
            ],
        ],
```

**Register your Model in config file**
       You have to add new section for service manager and provide your model classes there.

```
// Add this section:
        'service_manager' => [
            'aliases' => [
                Model\PropertyInterface::class => Model\PropertyTable::class,
            ],
            'factories' => [
                Model\PropertyTable::class => InvokableFactory::class,
            ],
        ],
```

Now only thing left is add functions in your PropertyInterface and Implentation in PropertyTable for them and then call them in your controller

This  [Complete Steps for implementation](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/in-depth-guide/models-and-servicemanager/#writing-a-factory-class)  Helped me in implementing the new flow.

Thanks to community. You all are best.

Comment: Glad you finally fix your problem, if my answer helped you to fix your problem, an upvote could be nice by the way...

Answer (score 2):

As long as the new factory interface in ZF3 is:

```
interface FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Create an object
     *
     * @param  ContainerInterface $container
     * @param  string             $requestedName
     * @param  null|array         $options
     * @return object
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null);
}
```

you have to implements your factory like this.

For helping you, you can use that [link](http://zendframework.github.io/zend-servicemanager/migration/)

EDIT :

In practise you should have this :

```
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
{
    $propertyTable = $container->get('Application\Model\PropertyTable');
    return new Controller($propertyTable);
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the right direction,
I looked up on web about your answer and Came across **this** [link](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/in-depth-guide/models-and-servicemanager/#writing-a-factory-class)
I implemented code from this link, and got quite successful here. only problem with following this code is now I can't access adapter object for my sql Queries.
can you help me out here, In my PropertyTable Model, How can I inject Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter class object. so that I can use it like this :
 `$sql = new Sql($this->adapter);`

Comment: @PankajJha Edited

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```php
/**
 * Retrieve service manager instance
 * @throws \Psr\Container\ContainerExceptionInterface
 * @throws \Psr\Container\NotFoundExceptionInterface
 * @return ContainerInterface
 */
public function getServiceLocator()
{
    return $this->getEvent()->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In ZF3 it is not recommended to pass service locator into controller.
You need to get all your dependencies from $container inside factory of the controller and pass they into the controller through the constructor (or setters).

Comment: can you show me an example using setter? or any link

Comment: @Athar just type in "php dependency injection setter" in search here or in google. There are many articles on this topic.