# Zend Framework - ERROR on CentOS 7 after installation

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, centos7

In CentOS 7, ZF2 was mirrored from another server for the first time ZF2 gives following error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to load ZF2. Run`php composer.phar install`or define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.' in /home/www/html/manager/init_autoloader.php:48\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/www/html/manager/public/index.php(9): require()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /home/www/html/manager/init_autoloader.php on line 48`

Therefore, i have done following

```
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar update
```

and since then it keeps failing forever:

```
[Mon Feb 19 10:13:00.129063 2018] [:error] [pid 7763] [client 4xxxxxx:60336] PHP Deprecated:  You are retrieving the service locator from within the class Application\\Controller\\IndexController. Please be aware that ServiceLocatorAwareInterface is deprecated and will be removed in version 3.0, along with the ServiceLocatorAwareInitializer. You will need to update your class to accept all dependencies at creation, either via constructor arguments or setters, and use a factory to perform the injections. in /home/www/html/manager/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php on line 258
```

How do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The `composer update` and `composer install` commands does very different things.

While `composer install` installing all of predefined dependencies in specific versions as found in `composer.lock` file, `composer update` tries updating them to latest versions and writes a new lock file.

Since the `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` removed from controllers in recent versions as stated in [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974794/getservicelocator-in-zend-framework-3) and [this thread on GitHub](https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/issues/7682), you need to use `composer install` if you just want to mirror an existing project while keeping the functionality as is.

Comment: So i do `rm -fr /home/www/html/manager; git clone git@myproiject.git; php composer.phar install` ? But then it will again give this error, which i had last time `Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "composer.phar self-update" to get the latest version.                                                                                       
  [LogicException]                                                                     
  Can not find "zendframework/zendframework-2.0.3" package in registered
`

Comment: You can still update the composer's itself first, there is nothing wrong with it: `php composer.phar self-update` after that `php composer.phar install` should work since v2.0.3 still available here: https://packagist.org/packages/zendframework/zendframework#2.0.3

Comment: I did `rm -fr /home/www/html/manager; git clone git@myproject.git; php composer.phar self-update; php composer.phar install;` Still same failed.

Comment: "same failed" meaning what?